# EF6 Add entity to a collection only using it's Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a problem i need to add an entity to a collection with reading it from EF.
Because the entity the collection belongs to get added later into another context.

Example
Entity Event is created and saved to the EFContext 1 and get ID 1.
Events needs to be saved here, and later added to the collection.

Entity Car is created but not added or saved to a context.
Car is passed around between a few functions and after a user clicks a button.
Car is passed to another class and there added to a second DBContext (2).
Or possible the user cancels and the car is not saved and the Event lives as proves it happend.

Car has a collection of events as property.
I want to add Event to this collection but only by using it's id, because car is later added and saved by the another DBContext 2.

Normally i want load Event from the current DBContext and add that one to the car entity. But then two DBContexts gets mixed.
What i want is something like `Car.Events.Add(new Event() {EventId == 1});`
But this wants to create a new event which is not what i want.

I can't access the relation table (through EF) because is EF generated.

Is what I want even possible?

Comment: Please show the classes. It's not clear what the relationship between car and event looks like (I *guess* many-to-many, but with or without junction class?).

Comment: The classes, yes, but also code that uses them the way you *want* to use them to help understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are options that might suit your scenario, but I would advise caution when working with bounded contexts without accepting the cost of loading entities in each context that references them. In the case where one DbContext has created an Event, but another DbContext creates a car that you want to bind to that existing event, knowing that event ID, you can do something like this:

```
using (var carContext = new CarContext())
{
   var event = new Event { Id = eventId };
   carContext.Events.Attach(event);
   var car = new Car { /* ... */ };
   car.Events.Add(event);

   carContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the second context is more long-lived, such as scoped to a web request etc. then you should search the context for the event first, using that reference, before attaching the event.

```
Event event = carContext.Events.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == eventId);
if (event == null)
{
   event = new Event { Id = eventId };
   carContext.Events.Attach(event);
}
// ...
```

This will throw exceptions on SaveChanges if that event had not been persisted, or has since been deleted before this code gets called.

Generally if I have bounded contexts where a Car context needs to know about Events, but only cares about reading/associating them to cars, and only needs a couple of columns, I map a simplified Event entity model to events containing just the fields I need, then I can inexpensively load these in the context. If the Event table for instance had 30 columns, but as far as Cars were concerned I just needed the Event's Id, Name, and DateTime, my CarContext would map a lightweight Event entity with just those 3 columns rather than the full Event entity definition. That way my car context can load and associate that event safely and cheaply:

```
using (var carContext = new CarContext())
{
   var event = carContext.Single(x => x.Id == eventId); // Selects 3 columns from DB or can load from cache for longer-lived contexts. I get an exception here if the Event doesn't exist rather than SaveChanges.
   var car = new Car { /* ... */ };
   car.Events.Add(event);

   carContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The caveat is that this lightweight event cannot be used to create Event rows unless it possesses all non-null-able fields, and even then only one DbContext should own the responsibility for inserting any non-trivial entity. I normally prefix the name of these entities with "Lw" for Lightweight, I.e. "LwEvent". These entities have a comment header to indicate they are not for use inserting.